# Picamera2.stop() Behavior - do controls persist?

Tags: python, camera, picamera

With Pycamera2 you can set controls e.g. autofocus. There doesn't seem to be a get_controls() function to verify what is set. Do the controls perist after using Picamera2.stop()?

Comment: have you tried running a test?

Comment: look at the `controls.py` example code ... it appears to be an example of reading controls values ... I have no way of testing it